# Position and Rotation of object with 4 Points (perspective view)

Tags: 3d, rotations

I am so confused about this. I found many links for example this one: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180102/how-to-calculate-3d-rotation-from-3-points)

What I have:

1. A perspective view with fixed position
2. An object with 4 points (Green) and a point (Red) like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. I know the size of all 5 points in all times.
4. I know the distance between all 5 points at all times.

If we assume center of screen (k) is (0,0,0) in 3D world. Is there a way to find the 3d position and rotation of "red" point?

I am not an expert but I know we can find the normal vector with 3 points ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137538/calculate-the-vector-normal-to-the-plane-by-given-points)). And also orientation of 3 points ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386810/orientation-of-three-points-in-3d-space)). And also this one with 2 points ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985795/find-3rd-point-in-3d-space-based-on-position-of-2-points)).

Comment: Are the four points a rectangle? What dimensions? If you know this data you may use affine techniques to determine the location of say a camera and from this the red point 3d Lication.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. green points are on a rectangle, red point may not be. It was an interesting topic that I will think about. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: Are all object on same plane?

Comment: @Moti Green Objects are on the same plane, red object may be on in and may not. it dependson the configurations. but its position retated to other 4 green object are always fixed.

Comment: In fact, 4 green dots should indicate the coordinates of a plane. The larger the green dot, the closer it is to us, and the smaller the dot, the farther away it is from us. The distance between these four points is always constant. I do not necessarily follow the final formulas. I'm mostly looking for names of math tools that can be used. For example, when I realized what a normal surface vector really does, I was able to use it to cut 3D shapes in C#.

Comment: By math tools I mean math concepts or principles.

Comment: May be this could be a place to start  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space